# How might I run web browsers from separate spaces (sandboxing)?

Tags: 16.04, xorg, firefox

**Situation:** In web development I need to be logged into an application as an *administrator*, *normal user*, *unauthenticated* user etc. I'd like to have a set up where each browser window is unaware of the other's logged in session.

**Question:** How can I have multiple browser windows open but have them running from different profiles or different cache areas? If firefox profiles, how can I achieve this *without* using the Profile editor UI?

Can I create a temporary user, run Firefox, then just throw away the entirety of that user account? Or, should I be using like a browser-in-a-VM?

## **What I've tried so far:**

### Bash

My first attempt was to try something like the following:

```
# create temp user
tmp_user=`head -c 10 /dev/random | base64 | head -c 10`

# create user
sudo useradd $tmp_user;

# run browser
sudo -u $tmp_user `which firefox`

# hold and wait then kill account
sudo userdel $tmp_user
```

I got so far as `sudo -u $tmp_user firefox` the following error displayed:

> sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
>
> sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
>
> No protocol specified
>
> Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
>   Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
>   Error: cannot open display: :0

### Firejail

I then tried [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/), however, I think I misunderstood what this prgoram was meant to do. The main firefox window and one started under `firejail firefox` was aware of each others login sessions.

Comment: A simple way would be to use Firefox's "Private browsing" mode, a private browsing window will be unaware of other Firefox windows, and won't share logins, cookies, and so on. Is something like this what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Look into using different Firefox profiles and the `firefox -no-remote` command-line option.  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiple_profiles for more info. @JonasCz 's solution is also a good one.

Comment: @JonasCz That works if I'm only worried about the admin role and a normal user. But that only gives me two distinct work spaces. I need about four distinct work-spaces where I can just throw away the session and start again.

Comment: @NickWeinberg Can I create new profiles on-the-fly and then delete them  in CLI/Bash? IF so, please suggest as an answer.

Comment: There's an addon called Multifox which will allow you to have more than two independent sessions at the same time.

Comment: Use `gksudo` instead of `sudo` for graphical applications.

Comment: @XToro gksudo is not always installed by default on Ubuntu; the preferred method is to use `pkexec`

Comment: You could try using `firefox -private -no-remote` to open a new private browsing session; all profile info from that session should be independent from other windows and is automatically deleted when the window is closed. If you give it a try, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Chromium, or Google Chrome, just tell it to use different data directories:

```
google-chrome --user-dir=/tmp/admin
google-chrome --user-dir=/tmp/unauth
google-chrome --user-dir=/tmp/normal
```

Then you can just delete these directories when you're done.

Or if you want random temporary directories:

```
google-chrome --user-dir=$(mktemp -d)
```

Comment: this works with firefox as well - `firefox --no-remote --profile "profiledir"` as long as "profiledir" exists, even if empty